# Creating Text/String Vectors Automatically With The Results of Webscraping [Python]

Tags: python, web-scraping, vector, vectorization

I need to put each speech that I took of the website of  brazilian's federal deputies speeches and debates and put them in a text vector separately so that I can use it with an API of a AI text-to-image generator, but do not know how and if it's possible to do this process automatically.

The code scraper I'm using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/sitaqweb/resultadoPesquisaDiscursos.asp"

params = {
    "txOrador": "Nikolas Ferreira",  # <-- change the name here
    "CurrentPage": 1,                # <-- increase the pages here
    "txPartido": "",
    "txUF": "",
    "dtInicio": "",
    "dtFim": "",
    "txTexto": "",
    "txSumario": "",
    "basePesq": "plenario",
    "CampoOrdenacao": "dtSessao",
    "PageSize": "50",
    "TipoOrdenacao": "DESC",
    "btnPesq": "Pesquisar",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(api_url, params=params).content, "html.parser")

for row in soup.select("tr"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")]
    if len(tds) > 2 and tds[2] == "BREVES COMUNICAÇÕES":
        u = "https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/sitaqweb/" + row.a["href"]
        u = u.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "")
        html_text = requests.get(u).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, "html.parser")
        print(soup.p.text)
        print("-" * 80)
```

Comment: Instead of `print`-ing the text, you could append it to a list? `speech_list.append(soup.p.text)`?